# Typical folder structure for a python project with unit and integration tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

What would be a typical structure and path/import conventions used? Would anyone have a link to a representative python project?

```
project.scratch/
    project/
        scratch/
            __init__.py
            dostuff.py
            tests/
                unit/
                    test_dostuff.py
                integration/
                    test_integration.py
```

Comment: https://github.com/languages/Python

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what you have shown, the typical python project structure is as follows.

```
├── app_name
    │
    ├── app_name
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── folder_name
    │   └── etc...
    ├── tests
    │   ├── unit
    │   └── integration
    ├── README.md
    ├── setup.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

```

This statement is largely due to personal experience, but it is also the structure advocated [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/tutorials/writing_tests.html#integration-vs-unit).

I have also seen an `integration_tests` directory as a sibling of the `tests` directory instead, but I believe that this is much less common.

Contrary to Bhavish Agarwal's answer, I see no mention of integration tests for Django (only integration tests using Django). It seems they decided not to have any.

Comment: I have also seen an integration_tests directory as a sibling of the tests directory instead, but I believe that this is much less common. -> So where would be the right place ? I currently have my structure similar to what you have described but im not sure if this is right? Or is there no right or wrong way

Comment: @Naveen There is no right or wrong way. I like the structure that I provided because pytest will run both unit and integration tests together with both in the tests folder. It's still just personal opinion.

Comment: Advocated link is broken @JoshuaHoward

Comment: Adding what I think is the correct link @JoshuaHoward advocated here: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/writing_tests.html

Answer (score -2):

Since you asked for a typical structure, why look further than (arguably) the most famous python framework: [django](https://github.com/django/django)

Comment: Where can I find integration tests in django, and how would coverage tests be performed?

Comment: Please expand this answer with an actual structure, don't just link to somewhere else.